# Login session timeout

Tags: spring, spring-security

I would like to set a timeout for the login session of x minutes.

I have created a `SessionListener`:

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(60 *15);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) { }
}
```

Which create sessions with a timeout of 15 minutes but I would like to set this timeout once a user is login. Otherwise, if you wait more than 15 minutes in the login page and try to login, the session has been destroyed and you won't be able to login (and AccessDeniedHandler class is launched).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have a solution for that. The main reason why Spring creates a session even if the user is not authenticated is for the csrf token, so as soon as a page is open Spring will create a session. What I have done is set the session without timeout when it is created.

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) { }
}
```

Then, once a user is authenticated (with the login page) I set a timeout to the current session:

```
public class LoginSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Autowired
    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy;

    @Override
    protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {

        // Set session timeout when user is authenticated
        request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(5);

        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }

}
```

In this way the user can stay at login page as long as it want and the session will never be destroyed.

Comment: Thank you , this solution solved my problem also, not sure if this is the best way to handle this issue but it works. inside SessionListener i put a negative value for unlimited time:  setMaxInactiveInterval(-1)